# Hard drive thumping noise

Tags: hard-drive

I have an IBM ST2000NM0011, and it makes a thumping sound whenever I'm reading or writing to it. I got it from a friend, so I'm not sure when it started making the sound or if it's bad. Is the hard drive failing, or is it normal?

[Sound](https://gofile.io/?c=J2D293)

Comment: The model name suggests that its a slightly newer seagate - IBM hasn't made hard drives in a VERY long time. The thumping sounds... bad though.

Comment: The "legitimate" reason for a drive to make thumping sounds is as it moves the read/write heads back and forth. If that is what you have in the sound file is hard to tell. Check: make sure the drive isn't mounted mechanically - i.e. hold it in your hand - while running: does it still make the same sounds?

Comment: @Hannu I really like your recommendation about holding the drive in your hand to ensure it's not a mounting issue.  I will add that when doing so, I think it is best to make sure you are properly grounded.  As a result of your comment, I have added a note about mounting issues to my answer.

Comment: @Hannu When I originally wrote my answer (offline), I specified that my answer pertained to modern hard drives, because, indeed, *very early* generations of platter-based hard drives (well before when this drive was manufactured) did often thump when moving the heads, and often quite loudly.  But I couldn't accurately come up with a good definition of "modern", so I simplified my answer before posting it.  I think I came up with a reasonable edit to help clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Hard drives of that generation should not make **thumping** sounds.  The exception would be if they are improperly mounted.

That drive, a Constellation ES SATA drive, was likely manufactured in the early 2010's.

[Here](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/constellation-fam/constellation-es/constellation-es-1/en-us/docs/100650923f.pdf) is the reference manual for it, from Seagate.

It's likely failing.  I would not recommend using it for any important data.